# Send on codeIgniter result_array to access in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

When i load the codeIgniter file, the result i get using print_r is not sent to the view file. please any help?

Model

```
class Tether extends CI_Model {
public $table='';
public $primary_key='';

    public function fetch_data(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->order_by($this->primary_key,'desc');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();        
   }
```

Controller

```
    public function index(){    
    $task=new Tether;
    $task->table=$this->table;
    $query=$task->fetch_data();
    print_r($query);
    $this->load->view('layout_chart',$query);
```

print_r result is:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [trend_id] => 1 [month] => JANUARY [year] => 2015 [amount] => 10000 ) [1] => Array ( [trend_id] => 2 [month] => FEBRUARY [year] => 2015 [amount] => 15000 ) [2] => Array ( [trend_id] => 3 [month] => MARCH [year] => 2015 [amount] => 20000 )

Comment: can you show the code in the view? The results actually do get passed on to the view, you're probably not accessing them correctly

Comment: What is the error/output you are getting and what is the expected output, kindly specify?

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
$query['result'] = $task->fetch_data();
```

In the layout_chart view:

```
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Niall is correct. But, It's important to understand the mechanics of passing data to a view.

Data should be passed to `$this->load->view()` as an array. The keys of the array become the variables in the view. In other words, in the following code, we make an array with two keys `k1` and `k2` that is sent to the view.

```
$data = array('k1' => "Hello", 'k2' => "World!");
$this->load->view('hi_view', $data);
```

Then in`hi_view.php` the two array keys become the variables `$k1` and `$k2`.

```
<?php
echo $k1 . " " . $k2;  //outputs Hello World!
```

Hope that provides understanding in addition to "the answer".

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fixed it with the following amendment to the controller

```
$query['hi']=$task->fetch_data();

$this->load->view('hi_view', $query);
```

Thanks, guys for your support!